# UITableView loads but nothing displayed

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I build and run there is nothing displayed.  No text just empty cells.

Here is my code:

```
#import "plungerselection.h"

@implementation plungerselection
@synthesize tableData;

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Turbo", @"Hollow Turbo", @"Single Pad", @"Dual Pad", @"Bullet", nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


#pragma mark - TableView Data Source Methods 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;{

    return [tableData count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have wired up the datasource and delegate connections in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the text in the cell if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns `nil` which in this case doesn't happen (and even if it did it will only happen a few times before all the cells that are needed get in the queue). You should set the text outside of the `if (cell == nil)`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```